# Javascript: show the element in the middle of screen doesn't work with fixed postion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need the element vertically on the middle of the screen when the button is clicked, and no matter how browser's height is adjust, it will always in the middle.

```
 <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button id="button">click me</button>
    <div id="element">balah</div>
    </html>


<style>
#element{
    position: fixed;
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

I tried:

```
<script>
$("#button").click(function(){
    $('#element').css('margin-top',$(window).innerHeight()/2);

})
</script>
```

Comment: its working from what I see https://jsfiddle.net/b14a8bou/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use JS, this can be done with pure CSS;

```
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calc the position on the screen considering the element too...

```js
function FixDivCtrl() {
  var btn = $('#test');
  var target = $('#element');
  
  btn.click(function() {
    var coords = {
      "margin-top": target.height() / -2,
      "margin-left": target.width() / -2,
      "position": "fixed",
      "left": "50%",
      "top" : "50%"
    };
    target.css(coords);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(FixDivCtrl);
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test">Make it Fixed</button>

<div id="element"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a cuss class with Top,l,r,b set to 0px, margin: auto and position fixed.

Not tested , but you can use addClass and removeClass to add the new cuss class.

For example:
 $(your-element).addClass("center");

```css
div.center {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  Top:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  Bottom:0px;
  Position:fixed;
  Margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="test">Make it Fixed</button>

<div id="element"></div>
```